# Turn file into list

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I have a file.txt like this:

```
Hello
Bye
Good
```

and I want to turn it into

```
s = ["Hello", "Bye", "Good",]
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: You should provide a MCVE in a problem like this, and the error (or wrong actual output vs desired output) you get.

Comment: What you show there is a list, not an array. You will get one with `readlines()` on an open file.

Comment: How were you trying to use `np.asarray`?  What argument?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy to do,

```
s = open(filename, 'r').readlines()
```

Comment: Don't forget to close() the file if you use this method

Answer (score 0):

This is my usual method:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    file = f.read()
mylist = []
for line in file:
    mylist = mylist.append(line)
```

Comment: Just an FYI you don't have to specify the "r" here... unless reading binary ie "rb" :)

Comment: Never realized that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this has already been answered many times. But here it is:

```
>>> s = []
>>> with open('f.txt') as file_in:
...     s = file_in.read().split()
... 
>>> s
['Hello', 'Bye', 'Good']
```